# Can't load a push url from my Web View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, storyboard, interface-builder

When I receive my push notification, from my app delegate I handle the push in `handleRemoteNotifications:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` and from there I call a `firstViewController` class method to send the push url, like this:

```
-(void)handleRemoteNotifications:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // get link
    NSDictionary *aps = (NSDictionary *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    if ([aps objectForKey:@"link"])
    {
        NSString* jobID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[aps objectForKey:@"link"]];

        NSLog(jobID,nil);

        [FirstViewController viewController:jobID];
    }
}
```

this is my firstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>



@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *firstview;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *back;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *stop;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refresh;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forward;


+(void)viewController:(NSString*)link;
- (void)updateButtons;
@end
```

An I'm trying to load the received push url in the current webView like this:

```
+(void)viewController:(NSString*)link{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    FirstViewController *new = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    [new loadPush:(NSURLRequest*)requestObj];

}
-(void)loadPush:(NSURLRequest*)requestObj{

    [_firstview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Everything works fine when I compile, except the url don't load. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Can you put a NSLog after NSURL *url to test the link string and check the NSURL is not nil? Then if you receive a good URL, try to test it on your browser.

**EDIT:**

Maybe you have to add a webView on the new ViewController instanced.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]     initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

self.webView = webView;

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
```

Comment: I've already did that and the link is ok. I think it's because I'm creating a new instance of the viewController, but I don't know how else do that...